# console.log as condition in if statement

Tags: if-statement, console.log

Why isn't the if-statement on the bottom computing true?

Is it maybe not possible to use console.log as condition in an if-statement together with a number?

```
// This is what a function looks like:

var divideByThree = function (number) {
    var val = number / 3;
    console.log(val);
};

// On line 12, we call the function by name
// Here, it is called 'dividebythree'
// We tell the computer what the number input is (i.e. 6)
// The computer then runs the code inside the function!
divideByThree(6);

if (divideByThree(6) === 2)
{console.log("I'm right")}
else
{console.log("I'm stupid")}
```

this certainly works

```
var divideByThree = 2;

if (divideByThree === 2)
{console.log("I'm right no.2")}
else
{console.log("I'm stupid no.2")}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439380/javascript-use-of-variables-basic-functions

Comment: you are not returning the result of divideByThree, so it will retrun undefined which is not equal to 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not returning the result of divideByThree, so it will retrun undefined which is not equal to 2

EDIT
add return to the function

```
var divideByThree = function (number) {
    var val = number / 3;
    console.log(val);
     return val;
};
```

Comment: Do you mean by this that by using "divideByThree(6);" I'm not returning the result of divideByThree but instead the console.log of the result of divideByThree? If yes, how would I return the result or how would the expression compute to true?

Comment: thank you! i guess that i can't work with a console.log for anything other than printing to console, which makes sense.